# BIOS black screen when drives are connected

Tags: boot, bios

I probably messed up my bios settings some time ago and now I have a problem with it.
When I try to access everything I see is just a black screen. And this happens all the time.

It turns out that it works normally only without drives connected (HHD, SSD or even USB make my BIOS turn black). Does anyone know if there is an easy way to solve this (assuming this to be a stupid issue) or maybe have some other advice to get into it? Thanks!

**Motherboard:** ASUS Z-170A

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be a hardware rather than a Unix/Linux problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't even boot into your BIOS, it's not a problem with your OS.  This site is specifically for Unix & Linux.

That being said, it's probably a hardware issue.

[The Manual](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/Z170-A/HelpDesk_Manual/) shows that there are several LEDs on that motherboard to help you isolate the problem.  These are:

- PWR LED
- DRAM LED
- CPU LED
- VGA LED
- BOOT DEVICE LED

If you have a videocard, try connecting your monitor to the on-board graphics of your mobo instead.  This is a simple test to rule out your videocard (though I don't think it would be that).  If the DRAM LED is on, re-seat your memory, or change which slots they are installed in (though I don't think faulty RAM would prevent the BIOS from running).

Since none of HDD, SSD, USB work, it's probably not your specific drives.  It's probably not even your SATA or USB chipsets.

I would first replace the power-supply.  It's the cheapest thing to replace and could be failing to provide the power to these buses.

If that doesn't work, I'd think about replacing the motherboard.

Since you're on this site, I assume you use Unix or Linux.  One of the nice things about these OSs is that if you do change your motherboard, things will probably continue to work.  In a worst-case, as long as you can get to a shell, you can re-initialize your hardware configuration.  On Arch linux the command is `mkinitcpio -p linux`, on Debian it's `update-initramfs -u`.